# how to change column display order using table() in r

Tags: r

I am using the table() function in r to create a contingency table. The table displays columns for 'No' and 'Yes' by default, however, I would like the columns to display results for 'Yes' and 'No'. Is there a way to achieve this? Thank you

My code:

```
data$skull_fractures_i<-ifelse(! (data$`Skull Fractures` %in% c("Not idenfitied",'Not identified','Heart only autopsy','Had craniotomy at hospital')), 'Yes', 'No')  
data$age_i<-ifelse(data$`Age Deceased`<=65, '<=65 years old', '>65 years old')
table(data$age_i, data$skull_fractures_i)
```

I have:

```
               No  Yes
<=65 years old 24   45
>65 years old  40   50
```

I want:

```
               Yes  No
<=65 years old 45   24
>65 years old  50   40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your factor levels before `table`:

```
data$skull_fractures_i <- factor(data$skull_fractures_i, levels = c("Yes", "No"))
```